# iOS AWS API Gateway : Unauthenticated access is not supported for this identity pool

Tags: aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito, aws-ios

```
//setup service config
    AWSServiceConfiguration *serviceConfiguration = [[AWSServiceConfiguration alloc] initWithRegion:CognitoIdentityUserPoolRegion credentialsProvider:nil];


    //create a pool


    AWSCognitoIdentityUserPoolConfiguration *configuration = [[AWSCognitoIdentityUserPoolConfiguration alloc] initWithClientId:CognitoIdentityUserPoolAppClientId  clientSecret:nil poolId:CognitoIdentityUserPoolId];

    [AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool registerCognitoIdentityUserPoolWithConfiguration:serviceConfiguration userPoolConfiguration:configuration forKey:@"UserPool"];

    AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool *pool = [AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool CognitoIdentityUserPoolForKey:@"UserPool"];

    pool.delegate = self;

    AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider *credentialsProvider = [[AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider alloc] initWithRegionType:CognitoIdentityUserPoolRegion
                                                                                                    identityPoolId:CognitoIdentityPoolId];

    AWSServiceConfiguration *configuration1 = [[AWSServiceConfiguration alloc] initWithRegion:CognitoIdentityUserPoolRegion
                                                                          credentialsProvider:credentialsProvider];

    [AWSServiceManager defaultServiceManager].defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration1;
```

Above is my code in appdelegate.
I'm using sample from AWS document "CognitoYourUserPool" to login.
And trying to call API using Generated SDK for iOS.

```
 API_Client *apiInstance = [API_Client defaultClient];
    [apiInstance setAPIKey:@"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"];        
    [[apiInstance presetTypeGet] continueWithBlock:^id _Nullable(AWSTask * _Nonnull t) {
        NSLog(@"error: %@",t.error);
        NSLog(@"result: %@",t.result);
        return nil;
    }];
```

I did call the API after logged in. but it's error.
I dont know why for now.
Please help me. If you need more information please ask.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Did you mix up your configurations? First you set up a service configuration, than a configuration1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 2 days, I figure it out.

```
 AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider *credentialsProvider = [[AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider alloc] initWithRegionType:CognitoIdentityUserPoolRegion
                                                                                                    identityPoolId:CognitoIdentityPoolId identityProviderManager:pool];
```

Need to set identityProviderManager.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
AWSCognitoIdentityUserPoolConfiguration *configuration = [[AWSCognitoIdentityUserPoolConfiguration alloc] initWithClientId:CognitoIdentityUserPoolAppClientId  clientSecret:nil poolId:CognitoIdentityUserPoolId];

AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider *credentialsProvider = [[AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider alloc] initWithRegionType:CognitoIdentityUserPoolRegion identityPoolId:CognitoIdentityPoolId];
AWSServiceConfiguration *configuration1 = [[AWSServiceConfiguration alloc] initWithRegion:CognitoIdentityUserPoolRegion credentialsProvider:credentialsProvider];

[AWSServiceManager defaultServiceManager].defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration1;

[AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool registerCognitoIdentityUserPoolWithConfiguration: configuration1 userPoolConfiguration:configuration forKey:@"UserPool"];

AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool *pool = [AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool CognitoIdentityUserPoolForKey:@"UserPool"];

pool.delegate = self;
```

Comment: I did try. Same error happen. Did you implement AWS Cognito?

Comment: No, took the changes from https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-ios-samples/issues/77

Comment: Thanks ivion, I find out the problem. I have posted the answer.